# How to call static methods in a class

Tags: c#, arrays, function

i defined the array and the functions but i'm having trouble calling the function, should i call a function using class name or object

```
public static string PrintArray (int [,] arr)
    {
        string output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.GetLength(0);i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                output += arr[i,j];
            output = output.Substring(0, output.Length)+"/n";
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static void Fill(int[,] arr,int min, int max)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            arr[i] = r.Next(min, max);
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                arr[i,j] = r.Next(min, max);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: These are `static` methods, so from the class is best.

Comment: A comment which is not related to your question: You can shorten this code `output = output.Substring(0, output.Length)+"/n";` into `output = ouput + "/n";`, even shorter `output += "/n";`

Answer (score 2):

If you have `static` methods, they must be called using the class name. You would only call from an object if it was an `instance` (non-static) method, it is not possible to call a `static` method from an instance of an object, or an `instance` method from a static class name.

In your case, as you have defined `static` methods, you must reference them in a static way. e.g., if your class was called `ArrayHelper`

```
public class ArrayHelper
{
    public static string PrintArray (int [,] arr)
    {
        string output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.GetLength(0);i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                output += arr[i,j];
            output = output.Substring(0, output.Length)+"/n";
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void Fill(int[,] arr,int min, int max)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            arr[i] = r.Next(min, max);
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                arr[i,j] = r.Next(min, max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could use it like so

```
var array = ...
ArrayHelper.Fill(array, 10, 20);
```